# IP TABLES port forwaring corrupts my packets?

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

Here's my scenario.

I have a WORKING DAEMON receiving packets through a proprietary protocol (mounted on the port `5000`) that has been working flawlessly for over a decade.

I have a weird problem though.

I have a FIREWALL which have our public IP ADDRESS that does a PORT REDIRECTION with IPTABLES like this:

```
IPT=iptables
LUISANA=192.168.0.1 
LOCAL_IF=eth0
INET_IF=eth1
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $LOCAL_IF -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to $LUISANA:5000
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $INET_IF -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to $LUISANA:5000
```

Here, `LOCAL_IF` and `INET_IF` are my two NICs with local and public ip addresses respectively and `LUISANA` is the IP address of the machine that is on the local network running my daemon on port `5000`.

When I have the network under this configuration, `iptables` some incoming packets get corrupted on the transformation and the protocol fails. However, if I take down these two `iptables` and use a **ssh tunnel** to do the port forwarding, the protocol works flawlessly.

So my question is: what can be causing this packet corruption? May be it has something to do with endianness? (both machines, FIREWALL and LUISANA run the same LINUX version on the same x86 hardware).

Comment: What exactly gets corrupted? Have you tried running wireshark on the target machine, to see what the recieved packets look like, and what's wrong/changed?

Comment: I have. Some `int` values get corrupted. Don't know why. It's a really weird problem. Back when my firewall was FreeBSD, I had the exact same problem though. So I don't know. I was expecting this to be a common problem but apparently it is not.

Comment: Are those values always in the same place (offset)? And are those values in the "data" part of tcp? Checksums get recalculated when dealing with NAT.

Comment: Yes. It's the DATA part of TCP.